# Difference between [...]int{} and []int

Tags: go

```
A -> var list1 = [...]int{}
B -> var list2 []int
```

I am new at golang...

I read some documents but , I still cant understand how to initialize list

What is difference between A and B?

Comment: One is an array (fixed size list), the other a slice (variable sized list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you tell the compiler number of elements while declaring, compiler creates an array of fixed size.

```
list1 := [3]int{2, 3, 4} // You are explicitly letting the compiler know about the length of array

list1 := [...]int{2, 3, 4} // Compiler will count the number of elements, and initialise an array of the count
```

NOTE - you can create an array larger than the no of elements you want to initialise it for by the first method, but not smaller (obviously)

```
list1 := [10]int{2, 3, 4}  // Is correct
list1 := [1]int{2, 3, 4}  // Is INCORRECT
```

An array is fixed in size.

When you declare it in this way:

```
list2 := []int{2, 3, 4}
```

This is a slice, which can grow as needed.

Refer to this article for understanding it better with examples:
https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/arrays-vs-slices/

Answer (score 2):

`list1` is an array, The length is fixed, `...`represents the number of array elements.

`list2` is a slice